# Duplicate :[Is there any documentation about using Client ID / Token with REST API to access Group and Professional Editions?]

Tags: api, appexchange, rest

I know my question is similar to other topic as mentioned in title but there are few points that I would like to clarify:

My Scenario: I have created an APP and it uses REST API functionality. currently this app is in AppExchange and it cleared the review check.

Issue : My customer which are having professional edition is facing few issue and they are getting "insufficient access" issue . and Customers which are having other edition are able to work fine with my app.

Question : Is it that if I submit a case with salesforce as mentioned in other question (Present with Title), and once the REST API is enabled by Salesforce then all my customer of professional Edition will be able be to work fine with my App and they would not get any issue such as "insufficient Access".

Please clarify once again.

Answer (score 1):

If the client is Professional+API, they can use the REST API. This usually costs money, and is a contractual agreement. Salesforce occasionally changes policy on if they allow this. The usual stance seems to be "if you want API access, upgrade to Enterprise."

Edit: it seems I was mistaken. You can request GE/PE access by requesting it for your connected app. See [this document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_rest_api_access.htm). Basically, you just have to ask via the partner portal.

Comment: Thank for the reply .Does this mean that all my customers which are using professional edition has to enable API Permission then only they can use this APP and there is no any other way.

Comment: You can only use the soap API for now. It's fairly inconvenient, given they give a great new API then crippled it for vendors.

Comment: It is really bad, I have created an APP which uses REST API functionality and currently it cleared review check but irony is that most of my customer used Professional Edition and they can't use this APP. All my energy and effort seems to be going in waste.

Comment: @arjunsingh I'm still waiting for them to fix this. It is almost a crime that we can't access the newest API, and instead have to import old, bulky code just to access Professional Edition.

Comment: I updated this answer with more information.